# JAVAFX: Passing data between FXML not Working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I've searched  several times here for answer but didn't get my solution.

**In my case:**
I want to take input from user and check validity. If everything is fine I will grab users *ID* from database and send that *ID* to another FXML and then run a select query there using that *ID* and display the results into a tableView.

In 2nd FXML (controller) I am using *initialize()* method to set data into tableView and a setId() method to receive user *ID* from previous FXML. But, initialize() method get called before setId() method and doesn't provide my required result as the ID is null.

Used [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml?lq=1) this method form passing data between FXML.

What will be the best solution for this?

FYI: Currently I'm using an extra class with static variable to store ID.

Comment: You may set the data of tableview on setId().

Comment: Thank you for your tips. It works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a controller factory that initializes the id before it returns the controller instance:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
loader.setControllerFactory(c -> {
    MyController controller = new MyController();
    controller.setId(userId);
    return controller;
});
...
Node n = loader.load();
```

This way you could also use classes as controllers, that don't provide a default constructor. A more complex controller factory could be used to connect model and presenter ([see MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)).

An alternative would be to modify the scene's contents in the `setId` method instead of the `initialize` method, which would be simpler than using a controller factory.

What the best solution is depends on your needs and personal preference. However, using a `static` member to pass data should be avoided, if possible.

Comment: Use `setController` instead of `setControllerFactory` in this case. If you really want to use `setControllerFactory`, you need to be much more careful as you will break `<fx:include>`s (in a pretty horrible way) with this (the included FXML files use the same controller factory to create their controller instances).